# How to load a subgrid statically?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, subgrid

I don't want use ajax to load data in my grid. Theres a way to load all data to main grid and subgrids statically?

In the samples from jqGrid Documentation, the parameter  `subGridUrl`, is needed. But I want something like:

```
var mydata = [ {
// ... some static code for data creation here
 } ]
```

and using mydata in parameter `data`, but subGrid don't have this parameter or something else.

Comment: please add some details or code...

Comment: Well there are two ways 1) you can pass it as part of the originating request;  or 2) generate it on client side (depending on the nature of data). 

It's a trivial question if you want to avoid ajax just avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [subgrid as grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid_as_grid) you have to create new grid inside of `subGridRowExpanded` callback. The callback get `rowid` as a parameter. So if you would get the array of data which can be used as `data` parameter of the subgrid the subgrid can be defined with `datatype: 'local'`.

The code schema can be about the following:

```
var mainGridData = [
        {id: 'm1', ...},
        {id: 'm2', ...},
    ],
    subgridData1 = [
        {id: 's11', ...},
        {id: 's12', ...},
    ],
    subgridData2 = [
        {id: 's21', ...},
        {id: 's22', ...},
    ],
    subgridByMainGridId = {
        m1: subgridData1,
        m2: subgridData2
    };

    $('#mainGrid').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        data: mainGridData,
        ....
        subGrid: true,
        subGridRowExpanded: function(subgridId, rowId) {
            var subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";

            $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridId)).html('<table id="' +
                subgridTableId + '"></table>');
            $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridTableId)).jqGrid({
                datatype: 'local',
                data: subgridByMainGridId[rowId],
                ...
            });
    });
```