# Jquery : load subgrid dynamically in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to make a Dynamic jqgrid which consists subgrid. So it means subgrid should load data from database according to main jqgrid.So i am not able to get the logic for loading subgrid dynamically according to main jqgrid.
Here I am posting my code for my js file

```
var InstructorsTabSc = function() 
{
var that = {};
var _parent = null;
var _instructorDlgMgrC = null;  
var _view = null;
var _panel = null;
var _path = null;
var BEGIN = "BEGIN";
var STARTING = "STARTING";
var READY = "READY";
var END = "END";
var _state = BEGIN;
var _transition = function(newState) {
    _state = newState;
    switch(_state) {
        case STARTING: _enterStarting(); break;
        case END: _enterEnd(); break;
    }
};
that.create = function(parent, path, panel) {

    _parent = parent;
    _path = path;
    _panel = panel;
    _transition(STARTING);
};      
that.destroy = function() {

    _transition(END);
};  
var _enterStarting = function() {

    var path = _path + '/InstructorsDlgMgrC';
    modelMgr.loadInclude( path + '/InstructorsDlgMgrC.js', function() {
        modelMgr.getHTML( _path + '/InstructorsTabSc.html', function(html) {

            _instructorDlgMgrC = InstructorsDlgMgrC();
            _instructorDlgMgrC.create(that, path);

            var req = {
                    programId :$('#programsList').val()
            };
            var fnSuccess = function(res) {
                _view = InstructorsTabV();
                _view.create(that, _panel, html, res);
            };
            serviceMgr.loadInstructor(req, fnSuccess, fnFailOrError, fnFailOrError);        
        });
    });
};      
var _enterEnd = function() {

    if (_view != null) {
        _view.destroy();
        _view = null;
    }

    _path = null;
    _parent = null;
};
return that;    
};      
var InstructorsTabV = function() 
{

var that = {};
var _sc = null; 
var _panel = null;      
that.create = function(sc, panel, html, res) {  
    _sc = sc;
    _panel = panel;
    that.layoutUi(html, res);
};      

that.layoutUi = function(html, res) {
    $(_panel).html(html);
    that.initInstructorGrid(res);
};

that.destroy = function() {
    $(_panel).html('');
    _sc = null;
};

that.initInstructorGrid = function(data) {      

    var grid = $("#instructorGrid");
        grid.jqGrid({
        data: data.instructors,
        datatype: "local",
        colNames:['Name','User ID', 'Is Active'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'firstName',index:'id', key: true, width:300},
            {name:'email',index:'Sname', width:370, formatter:'email'},
            {name:'isActive',index:'name',width:170,align:'center',editable: true, formatter: 'checkbox',formatoptions:{disabled:false}}
        ],
        pager:false,
        pgbuttons: false,
        pgtext: null,
        toppager:false,
        sortname: 'id',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: false,
        autowidth: true,
        height: "100%",
        subGrid: true,
        subGridOptions: { "plusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
                          "minusicon" :"ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
                          "openicon" : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
                          "reloadOnExpand" : false,
                          "selectOnExpand" : true },
        subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
            var subgrid_table_id, pager_id; subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
            pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
            $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({

            data: data.subjects,
            datatype: "local",
            colNames: ['Subject','Is Active','Sessions'],
            colModel: [ {name:"subjectName",index:"num", key: true, width:270},
                        {name:"sessionCount",index:"item",width:160,align:'center',editable: true, formatter: 'checkbox',formatoptions:{disabled:false}},
                        {name:"programUserId",index:"qty",width:380}], 

            pager: false,
            pgbuttons: false,
            pgtext: null,
            sortname: 'num',
            sortorder: "asc",
            autowidth: true,
            height: '100%' });

            $("#gview_"+subgrid_table_id).attr("style","border-left:1px solid #666;");
            $("#"+pager_id).attr("style","height:40px");
            $("#"+"pg_"+pager_id +" table"+" tbody" +" tr").attr("style","background:#FFF");
        }
    });

};
return that;    
};
```

And here is code for servlet

```
 @WebServlet("/app/LoggedInSc/AdminSc/AdminTabsetSc/PeopleSc/InstructorsSc/getInstructors")
public class GetInstructors extends JSONServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected JsonResponse action(TransactionHandler th, JSONObject json)  throws JSONException, CustomExceptionInvalidInput, Exception {       

    int programId = json.getInt("programId");

    List<Map<String, String>> instructorList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    List<Map<String, String>> subjectList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    for(ProgramUsersDetailDao daoProgramUser : ProgramUsersDetailDao.getProgramUsersByRole(th, programId, ProgramRoles.Instructor)) {

        instructorList.add(daoProgramUser.toMap());

        for(InstructorSubjectSessionsDao daoSubjectSessions : InstructorSubjectSessionsDao.getSubjectAndSessions(th, daoProgramUser.id))
        {
            subjectList.add(daoSubjectSessions.toMap());
        }
    }
    RESULT_OK.addDataParam("instructors", instructorList);
    RESULT_OK.addDataParam("subjects", subjectList);        
    return RESULT_OK;       
}
}
```

Please tell me how  to load data in subgrid according to main grid dynamically according to database

Comment: i got one idea, can i do this by comparing id in instructors with programUserid in subjects list ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to load data in subgrid *dynamically* why you don't use `subGridUrl`? You can load JSON data from the server directly instead of usage `datatype: "local"`.

In any way if you prefer to load all the data from the server as once you can place all data for all subgrids in the server response. It looks like `serviceMgr.loadInstructor` has `fnSuccess` callback which will be called at the end of data loading and the `res` parameter of `fnSuccess` get the data returned from the server.

Currently you use `data.instructors` in both grid and subgrid. You can format the data so that `data.subgridData[rowid]` will get you the subgrid data for the row with id attribute rowid. In the case you will need just replace the line

```
data: data.subjects,
```

in the subgrid to

```
data: data.subjects[row_id],
```

Comment: thanks for reply, you got it exactly right about service manager thing. But u read it wrong i am using data.subjets for subgrid data.

Comment: And i want data of subgrid should be according to main grid. so i think there should be some loop, which will compare both id's and will provide me the content. But again that's what i think. If you have any better and optimize solution please share

Comment: @VikasGupta: Sorry, I wrote not quite correct, but what I wanted to say is that you use **the same data** `data: data.subjects` in all subgrids independent from the row in which it will be opened. Now about the "loop". I think you don't full understand how subgrid will be created. Only if the user click on "+" (expand) button in the row the next row with subgrid will be created. If you use default setting `reloadOnExpand: true` the row will be deleted if the user close the subgrid. Because grid will be created with collapsed subgrids no subgrids exists initially so no "loop" can be done.

Comment: @VikasGupta: Look at the demo from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10178440/315935) to understand better what I mean with `data: data.subjects[row_id]`. [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9165978/315935) have very close code too.

Comment: Sorry but i am new to jquery, so how can i get this rowID. And can i use it just like 'data:data.subjects[rowID]' ?

Comment: @VikasGupta: You create subgrid inside of `subGridRowExpanded` and get `row_id` (the value of id attribute of the row (`<tr>`) which was clicked by the user). So you need just create `subjects` as array or as object *on the server*. The indexes (or the property names) should be the same which you use as ids or rows in the main grid.

Comment: sorry oleg, but i didn't get it. can you give any example of that ?

Comment: @VikasGupta: Because you need generate different sungrids for every row you should change `List<Map<String, String>> subjectList` to `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> subjectList`. One more thing: you should don't use different `name` and `index` values for local grids (`datatype: "local"`). So you should rename `{name:'email', index:'Sname'...}` to either `{name:'email', index:'email'...}` or `{name:'Sname', index:'Sname'...}`.

Comment: @VikasGupta: I posted you before two links with examples. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalSubgrid.htm) is from one from the references. You should generate on the server the data with the close structure to be able to use in the client code.

Comment: Helped me to load static data in your way, now changing servlet according to your way. but still thanks a lot man. great work. Keep it up.. :) :) :)