# jqGrid : Get data from a row that has been clicked within a heirarchical grid

Tags: jqgrid

Im currently working on a project which uses jqGrid with multiple subgrids.  I'm trying to get the rowid (and get at the data within the row) when a row is clicked or double clicked.  Eventually I would like to fill a text box with data from a clicked row.

I've tried a few variations using ondblClickRow and onSelectRow examples on here but wans't able to get it working.  I think I'm missing something really simple but don't see what.  So I went back and simplified it down as much as possible to just recognize the row click and display an alert.  This won't work for me either.

(based on the example in [jqGrid : issue loading nested sub grid with local datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767408/jqgrid-issue-loading-nested-sub-grid-with-local-datatype/13779589#comment19031920_13779589)) Look for the //***************
 part near the bottom..

```
var myData = [
// main grid data
     { id: "1", col1: "11", col2: "12",
         subgrid: [
                // data for subgrid for the id=m1
                    { id: "1", c1: "aa", c2: "ab", c3: "ac",
                        subgrid: [
                            // data for subgrid for the id=m1, subgridId=s1a
                            { id: "1", d1: "2aa", d2: "2ab", d3: "2ac" },
                            { id: "2", d1: "2ba", d2: "2bb", d3: "2bc" },
                            { id: "3", d1: "2ca", d2: "2cb", d3: "2cc" }
                        ]},
                { id: "2", c1: "ba", c2: "bb", c3: "bc" },
                { id: "3", c1: "ca", c2: "cb", c3: "cc" }
         ]},
    { id: "2", col1: "21", col2: "22",
        subgrid: [
            // data for subgrid for the id=m2
            { id: "1", c1: "1xx", c2: "1xy", c3: "1xz",
                subgrid: [
                    // data for subgrid for the id=m2, subgridId=s2a
                    { id: "1", d1: "2xx", d2: "2xy", d3: "2xz" }
                ]}
        ]},
    { id: "3", col1: "31", col2: "32" }
],
removeSubgridIcon = function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        idPrefix = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix");
    $this.find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td.ui-sgcollapsed").filter(function () {
        var rowData = $this.jqGrid("getLocalRow",
                $.jgrid.stripPref(idPrefix, $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")));
        return rowData.subgrid == null;
    }).unbind("click").html("");
},
isHasSubrids = function (data) {
    var l = data.length, i;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (data[i].subgrid != null) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
},
specificGridOptions = [
    {
        colNames: ["Column 1", "Column 2"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "col1" },
            { name: "col2" }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { width: 200 },
        sortname: "col1",
        sortorder: "desc",
        idPrefix: "s_",
        pager: "#pager",
        caption: "Demonstrate how to create subgrid from local hierarchical data"
    },
    {
        colNames: ["Colunm1", "Colunm2", "Colunm3"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "c1" },
            { name: "c2" },
            { name: "c3" }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { width: 112 },
        sortname: "c1",
        sortorder: "desc"
    },
    {
        colNames: ["Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "d1" },
            { name: "d2" },
            { name: "d3" }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { width: 90 },
        sortname: "d1",
        sortorder: "desc"
    }
],
commonGridOptions = {
    datatype: "local",
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    autoencode: true,
    height: "100%",
    //***************
    onSelectRow : function () 
    {
        alert('test!');
    },
    //also tried many variation on this
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid) 
    {
        alert(rowid);
    }
    //***************
    loadComplete: function () {
        // one can use loadComplete: removeSubgridIcon, but I included
        // curent implementation of loadComplete only to show how to call
        // removeSubgridIcon from your loadComplete callback handler
    removeSubgridIcon.call(this);
},
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
    var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
        subgridLevel = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "subgridLevel") + 1,
        parentIdPrefix = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"),
        pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(parentIdPrefix, rowId),
        localRowData = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", pureRowId);
    $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
    $subgrid.jqGrid($.extend(true, {}, commonGridOptions, specificGridOptions       [subgridLevel], {
        data: localRowData.subgrid,
        subGrid: isHasSubrids(localRowData.subgrid),
        subgridLevel: subgridLevel,
        idPrefix: rowId + "_",
        rowNum: 10000 // we use this to have no pager in the subgrids
    }));
}
};

$("#list").jqGrid($.extend(true, {}, commonGridOptions, specificGridOptions[0], {
    data: myData,
    subgridLevel: 0,
    subGrid: isHasSubrids(myData)
}));
```

Anyone have any ideas why it won't recognize the row click/double click?

Comment: You should include more code which shows how jqGrid are defined. The code which you posted don't contain the value of `datatype` option which you use. Do you use `loadonce: true` or not? How you fill the grid data? Typical error is that `id` of the grid will be incorrectly filled or the data have no `id` information at all. Moreover you wrote about filling of some "text box". What you mean? Do you use grid editing? Which editing mode and how you use?

Comment: I've edited the post to included the code from your original post(my code is similar). I'm using Local datatype, I don't use loadonce:true. I'm filling the grid data by making a call to a backend method to get the json data all at once when the page loads. By text box I just mean html input element type=text(probably should have left that out of the post, not important). The id's appear to be correct for my generated data. I don't use grid editing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote in comment that you get the data for the grid from the server. I suppose that the usage of `datatype: "local"` in the case is not the best choice. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935) where I described the way how to do the same, but using `datatype: "json"`.

Now I come back to your main question. I don't understand what text box (HTML input element) you want to fill and whether the input element is inside of the grid or outside of it. Nevertheless the only problem which you could probably have is the correct usage of `idPrefix` option of jqGrid.

It's very important to understand, that jqGrid use HTML `<table>` for representing of the body of grids. **Every `<tr>` element of the `<table>` must have `id` attribute in the current implementation of jqGrid**. So the `id` property from the input data will be used to assign the value of `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements. If one has more as one grid on the page or if one has grid with subgrids it's very easy to receive `id` duplicates which not allowed in all versions of HTML or XHTML.

Additional potential problem is the usage of numbers as `id` values. The most databases support auto-incremental datatype which is very practical as the key of the tables. In the case the native `id` (the key) for the database table and for the grid rows will be integer numbers. On the other side there are some additional restrictions depend on the version of HTML/XHTML which one uses. For example HTML5 specification says (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute))

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home
>   subtree and **must contain at least one character**. The value must not
>   contain any space characters.

So even though the most web browsers allows to use numbers as the values of `id` attribute it's not permitted and one can get compatibility problems in case of usage of this.

To solve all the described above problem jqGrid supports `idPrefix` options (which was introduced by the way based on my suggestion). In the case the value of `id` attribute will be build as concatination of `idPrefix` and the `id` from the input data. For example in case of `idPrefix: "s_"` and `id` values "1", "2", "3" used in the main grid of the example jqGrid will assign `"s_1"`, `"s_2"`, `"s_3"` as values of `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements of the main grid. The `rowid` of all callbacks will be the value from `id` attribute (`"s_1"`, `"s_2"`, `"s_3"`). If you need get the *original* `id` you can use `$.jgrid.stripPref` to strip the prefix. All ids which will be sent to the server by jqGrid will be normalized (`$.jgrid.stripPref` will be called) by jqGrid itself.

So the code which shows how to get data `onSelectRow` and `ondblClickRow` could be the following

```js
onSelectRow: function (rowid, stat, e) {
    myDebugTrace.call(this, "onSelectRow", rowid);
},
ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
    myDebugTrace.call(this, "ondblClickRow", rowid);
    e.stopPropagation();
},
...
```

where `myDebugTrace` function can be declared as

```js
var myDebugTrace = function (startingText, rowid) {
        var $this = $(this), p = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam"), rowData, col1,
            firstCol = (p.rownumbers ? 1 : 0) + (p.subGrid ? 1 : 0);

        rowData = $this.jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
        col1 = rowData[p.colModel[firstCol].name];
        $("<span>" + startingText + " on " + rowid + " (original id=" +
            $.jgrid.stripPref($(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"), rowid) +
            "). Data from the first column: \"" + col1 +"\"</span><br/>").appendTo("body");
    };
```

[The corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalSubgridMultileve3.htm) display the following on double-click on the row from the internal subgrid.

[image]

Comment: The issues I was having with the OnSelectRow was my fault and had to do with caching of my js.  In the end I needed to get the to level parent column id when clicking on any sub grid rows. The debugging function really simplified getting there.  Thanks Oleg!