# SlickGrid - table inside table (grid inside grid cell)

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, jqgrid, slickgrid

Does [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) support grid inside grid cell? Could you give example.

Data given is big JSON with internal arrays and objects.

Example:

```
  #    Name  D1 D2 D3 D4 D5
  Row1 Name1 Mn Tu We Th Fr
              2  3  5  6  2
              2  3  5  6  2
              2  3  5  6  2
  Row2 Name2 Mn Tu We Th Fr
              2  3  5  6  2
              2  3  5  6  2
```

What other grids (jqGrid, Flexigrid, DataTables etc.) could do that?

UPDATE: the terminology is not standard, so I just show the closest picture I have found

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The picture which you placed in your question looks more as one grid over another one, but you wrote about the **grid inside of cell** of another grid. So I am not sure that I correctly understand your requirements.

I can write only about jqGrid which I know. It supports [subgrids](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid), which means grids associated with **rows** of main grid. Main grid has additional column having "+" symbol by default. If the user click on the "+" symbol of some row the corresponding subgrid (general HTML fragment which can be another jqGrid) will by displayed under the row.

You can find examples of code which creates subgrids [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13779589/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14265456/315935) for example.

Comment: What is grid over another grid? How is it different to grid inside cell?

Comment: @PaulVerest: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. The grid inside of the cell has all grid elements (all column headers, cells and so on) inside of only one cell on the main (outer) cell. On your picture one can see two *separate* grids (with separate column headers and so on). Just two grids are placed on the page one over another.

Comment: @PaulVerest: For example [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AddClassToColumn1.htm) has column "Close" which contains checkbox in every row. If the grid *cell* would contains another grid you can imagine complex grid in instead on checkbox. Is it what you need?

Comment: Took the closest pic from you examples.