# jqGrid: How get all raw data, problems getting object inside object

Tags: javascript, json, datagrid, jqgrid

I have a grid which data is like this:

[image: Grid rows data]

As you can see, there are some rows (0,1,2 and 3 objets) and inside each there are more objects. Please pay attention that there is an object called '**datosPersonales**' ('personalData') with has inside more objets; nombre (name), apellido1(firstname) etc.

The problem arise when I try to get the data from one row:

```
var empleado = $("#GRID_empleado").jqGrid("getRowData",numRow);
```

What I get is and object with object inside but the the previously mentioned 'datosPersonales' objetc is not a 'father' of more objects. With an image (from firebug) is easier to understand:

[image: Data ungrouped in an object]

I don't know why but instead of get 'datosPersonales' with his 'sons' I get them like these:

- datosPersonales.nombre
- datosPersonales.apellido1
- datosPersonales.calle
- etc

What is the way to get all / whole / raw data from a certain row of a grid or even of the complete grid?

I have tried with some parameters but I've not been successful.

What I want is to get for example the data of [3] in the first image.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't posted any code which shows how you use jqGrid. Even such important options of jqGrid like `datatype` and `loadonce` are unknown. So I can only guess. I suppose that you create grid with subgrids to display all the data which you posted. I suppose that you use approach close to the way which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13779589/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935). In the way you can use either `getLocalRow` or  `.jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData")` instead of `getRowData`. If you don't know the answers which I referenced I recommend you to read there.